# Is stimming when praying alone considered permissable, if it helps me focus?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, makruh

When I am unable to pray in jamaat, I sometimes find myself [stimming](https://www.verywellhealth.com/adhd-stimming-5208900) to help me focus.

I wasn't clear from this [islam.qa question](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/12683/moving-whilst-praying) where my stimming fell in the categories?

> 1-Obligatory movements
>
> 2-Forbidden movements
>
> 3-Makrooh movements
>
> 4-Mustahabb movements
>
> 5-Permissible movements

If the stimming helps me focus, does it fit this or not:

> The forbidden movements are continuous movements done for no reason, because this kind of movement invalidates the prayer, and whatever invalidates the prayer is not permissible, because it is like mocking the signs of Allaah.

I feel like the stimming does have a purpose, as it increases my focus and kushoor.

However, externally it look as though it's simply 'continuous movements', which is filling me with self doubt (that is I'm not concerned how I look to people. But being honest with myself).

Is there a way of knowing?

Comment: By kushoor I guess you mean khushu' (~ concentrating on prayer)? Further I'm not familiar with the "stimming" what kind of movements do you do? Hm... let's say it this way an almost majority view would tell you to avoid praying alone, as it is considered fard or almost fard to pray in congregation.

Comment: @Jamalia, I pray in jamaat when I can. This question is about when that is not possible. Also please see my edit for what stimming is.